# getting wrong answer in pattern printing program

Tags: c, string

I have written the code to print a pattern in C. My expected answer is very different from the one that I am getting .I am very new to C language. I have debugged the code but unable to find the error. Please help me in finding the error. My code is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    //code
    int T,i,j;

    scanf("%d",&T);

    while(T--)
    {
        char str[5];
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            scanf("%c",&str[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        for(j=1;j<=5;j++)
        {
            for(i=0;i<5-j;i++)
            {
                printf(".");
            }
            for(i=0;i<j;i++)
            {
                printf("%c",str[i]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The input to the program is as follows:
Input:

```
1
geeks
```

The expected output of the program is as follows:
Expected output:

```
....g
...ge
..gee
.geek
geeks
```

The actual output of the program is as follows:
Actual output:

```
....
...
g..
ge.
gee
```

Comment: Notice that when you begin to read the word "geeks", you are actually starting at the space (" "), thus reading " geeks". This is why your first set of periods is not "....g"

Comment: `for(j=1;j<5;j++)` -->  `for(j=1;j<=5;j++)`

Comment: .. and `scanf("%c",&str[i]);` --> `scanf(" %c",&str[i]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correcting your bad code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //code
    int T,i,j;

    scanf("%d",&T);

    while(T--)
    {
        char str[5];
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            scanf(" %c",&str[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        for(j=1;j<=5;j++)
        {
            for(i=0;i<5-j;i++)
            {
                printf(".");
            }
            for(i=0;i<j;i++)
            {
                printf("%c",str[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

1. chars `scanf` format specifier changed to `" %c"` to consume the `'\n'` left into `stdin` by first `scanf`
2. The outer for loop must loop `5` times, so condition was changed to `<=` due to the started value that is `1`
3. Moved `printf("\n");` inside the outer for loop.

INPUT

```
1
geeks
```

OUTPUT

```
....g
...ge
..gee
.geek
geeks
```

other test

INPUT

```
2
1234567890
```

OUTPUT

```
....1
...12
..123
.1234
12345

....6
...67
..678
.6789
67890
```

Comment: very correct answer to a question full of erratic and suspect code.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solve your problem:

```
int main()
{
//code
int T,i,j;
scanf("%d",&T);
while(T--)
{
    char str[5];
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        scanf(" %c",&str[i]);  //first modification
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(j=1; j<=5; j++)  //second modification
    {
        for(i=0; i<=5-j; i++)
        {
            printf(".");
        }
        for(i=0; i<j; i++)
        {
            printf("%c",str[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```